# Execution order of an non-typical My-SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, execution

Assuming we've got table with following schema:

```
create table Test(id integer, title varchar(100));
insert into Test(id, title) values(1, "Hello");
insert into Test(id, title) values(20, "Hi");
```

Non-typical query in that case would be :

```
select * from Test where id= 20 < 2 AND SLEEP(1000000000) ;
-- sleep is being executed
select * from Test where id= 20 > 2 AND SLEEP(1000000000) ;
-- sleep is not being executed and nothing is going to be display
select * from Test where id = 20  > 0;
-- shows only one record , where id=20 /// "Hi"
select * from Test where id = 20  > -1;
-- shows whole table structure
```

Prior to this example, my question is what is happening in that specify moment of comparsion. Why it acting different if id=20 > 0 than id = 20 > -1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the query in question:

```
SELECT *
FROM Test
WHERE id = 20 > -1;
```

The reason the above returns the entire table is that the `WHERE` clause actually contains a range comparison, and is being evaluated as this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Test
WHERE (id = 20) > -1;
```

The expression `(id = 20)` will evaluate to either `1`, if true, or `0`, if false.  In either case, both zero and one will always be greater than `-1`, hence this query will always return all records.

Comment: i know right, but (id = 20) would be casted to 1, (and same situation 1>-1, 1>0) so why  if there is comparsion with 0 it will return only id=20 record? eg. select * from Test where id = 20  > 0; Oh, its not casting to 1 because 1 means error, 0 is the number casted... is that true..? Thanks in advance

Comment: Because `0 > 0` is false.  So you might phrase this by remarking that `id = 20` and `(id = 20) > 0` are really asserting the same thing.